# Where JWplayer default skin located and how we edit it

Tags: jwplayer6

i use jwplayer 6 , i think everybody know what is the default skin , but where is located  and how we can change the default player Though there is no file skin of it , here is snapshot of my jwplayer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFaX5.png)

i edit play/pause image on jwplayer.js file but it's not changes

```
background:"center no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,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)"
```